# Cordova InAppbrowser plugin is not working in Desktop web browser

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I'm developing a hybrid application. In my Application I'm trying to integrate the API using Oauth2 Authentication. So in my mobile version I'm using Cordova InAppBrowser plugin and its working in mobile devices. I'm trying the same set of code to work on Desktop web browser, but the *loadstart* does not trigger an event and I tried using the *load*event it does not seems to be working. Any help. Thanks in advance. Find the below working code.

var url1 = "xxx";

var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url1, '_system', 'location=yes');

```
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) 
        {
         alert('start: ' + event.url);
         if((event.url).indexOf("http://localhost.com:8085/callback") == 0){
         alert('start: ' + event.url);
         var requestToken = (event.url).split("code=")[1];
         alert('Token: '+requestToken);
        ref.close(); 
         }
    });
```

The code working on mobile devices.

Comment: inAppBrowser events don't work if you use `'_system'`

Comment: use window.open(url) that should work on all platforms. As said before don't use '_system' as this will try to open the phone's native browser (which doesn't exist on desktop)

Comment: I have been using the ** _blank** for the mobile devices. I have testing the **_system**  for Desktop browser. So I just copied the browser code. Is there any solutions to Desktop browser using the Cordova plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use feature detection to determine if you are on a Cordova platform and then you can take an `if(browser) do this ; else if(cordova) do that` approach. In other words, write conditional code so that when you are on a Cordova platform you use your inAppBrowser solution that works there and when you are in a browser use the solution that works best there.

You can detect if you are in a Cordova webview by testing for the existence of the `window.cordova` object (which is always present in a Cordova 3+ webview even if there are no plugins in your project). So you would do something like:

```
if( window.cordova ) {
    inAppBrowser solution ;
} else {
    standard browser solution ;
}
```

To be super safe, you should also include a test for the inAppBrowser, inside the test for the existence of `window.cordova` -- because JavaScript doesn't help you insure this at deployment, but that's just my opinion. :)

Comment: For InAppBrowser solution, I have did through **loadstart** event to capture the _requestToken_ from the callback URL. But standard browser solution, I tried to use  **load** event, the event did not fired. Is there any event listener to capture the callback URL from window.open in standard browser